# PHP - Pass Drop Down List option through query string

Tags: php, get, html-select, forms

I have a drop down list that has options that need to be passed through a query string.  How would I go about doing this?  Also, would anyone be able to list a way to do this both using a button and without using a button?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "passed through a query string"? As in a mysql query? and what do you mean by "without a button"? Are you wanting to use ajax to pass the data back to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="get">
<select multiple="multiple" name="things[]">
...
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php    
if(isset($_GET['things'])) {
    foreach($_GET['things'] as $thing) {
       echo $thing . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what the problem was that this solved. was it the use of the brackets in the name to make it an array?

Comment: @Anthony - he said 'options' so I figured he meant a multi-select and he was wondering how to get the array of selected options to the server, the gotcha being the [] after the select's name attribute, and knowing that turns $_GET['things'] into an array.

Comment: I actually had to removed the brackets in order for it to work.

Comment: @Nate Shoffner - are you using a multi or normal select?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jani's response, are you wanting to have the form submit without a button but still have a backup button if the user doesn't have javascript? You can use `noscript` to cover that:

```
<form action="script.php" method="get">
     <div>
     <select name="options" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>
     <noscript>
          <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
     </noscript>
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a button:

```
<form method="get">
<select multiple="multiple" name="things[]" onchange="this.form.submit()">
...
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: To be more accessible and backward compatible, I'd go with:

`<select multiple="multiple" name="things[]" onchange="this.form.submit()"><noscript><input type="submit" />`

Comment: erp...

<select multiple="multiple" name="things[]" onchange="this.form.submit()"><noscript><input type="submit" /></noscript>